# How to ignore a folder from the checks during eclipse renaming refactoring?

Tags: java, eclipse, renaming, automated-refactoring

When I rename a Java class in eclipse using the automated refactoring function (Alt+Shift+R), the checks take a very long time to complete. The reason is a subfolder which contains a large number of (non source) text files.

Is there a way to tell eclipse to exclude that folder from the checks during the renaming factoring without moving the folder?

Comment: Have you tried setting the derived flag to true in the properties of the folder that you want to exclude?

Comment: Thank you very much, I was totally unaware of that feature. If you post it as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude a folder from search, set the `Derived` flag to true in the properties of the folder you want to exclude.